# I am new to WordPress but I cant seem to add php code?

Tags: php, wordpress

So I wrote a script which checks if there is a session with a certain name or not and echoes hello world but after switching to WordPress I wasn't able to use any of my old scripts. Whenever I type them it thinks they are text and just prints it. So I tried a couple of stuff like a plugin that I could add my script in and it produces a shortcode that I can use. I tried that but it didn't worked. I can't find what is happening.

Are there some sort of logs I can refer to? If someone knows the fix please help (I'll leave the code down below). `result-id session` is a msg and `result session` is another message.

```
<?php
        if(isset($_SESSION['result-id'])){
           echo("hello world");
          else if(isset($_SESSION['result'])){
            echo $_SESSION['result'];
        }
        session_unset();
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start using sessions in WordPress you need to start it using an action hook:

```
function start_wp_session(){
    if( !session_id() )
        session_start();
}
add_action('init','start_wp_session');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to custom code in WordPress, first you must create a child-theme of your currently active theme. Then in the function .php file of your child theme folder, you can write any of your code. But you cannot start writing directly in function.php file. You must bind your code in a custom function, and then hook that function with any hooks present in the WordPress.

**Example hooks- wp_header, wp_footer, init, etc.**

See the example below.

```
function custom_function(){
    echo "Hello World!";
}
add_action('wp_head','custom_function');
```

You can wrap any code inside the custom function.